# How to set bounding boxes of groupplots for aligning purposes?

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment

How can I set the bounding box of a groupplot to the left and right outer axis of the subplots in the groupplot?

In my MWE are three plots and I want to align the outer axis of the groupplots with the first plot in the example.

The sum of the width of the groupplots is always \textwidth as the width of the bounding box of the first plot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\begin{axis} [xlabel=x, ylabel=y, height=3.7cm,width=\textwidth]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}

\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\useasboundingbox
(current axis.below south west)
rectangle (current axis.above north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,
              horizontal sep=0.02\textwidth, vertical     sep=0.02\textwidth,
              xticklabels at=edge bottom},
              height=3.7cm,width=0.49\textwidth]            
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y,yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y,yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot {rnd};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 2,
              horizontal sep=0.02\textwidth, vertical sep=0.02\textwidth,
              xticklabels at=edge bottom},
              height=3.7cm,width=0.32\textwidth]

\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot {rnd};                          
\nextgroupplot[ytick=\empty]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y,yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[ytick=\empty]
\addplot {rnd};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel=x, ylabel=y,yticklabel pos=right, ylabel near ticks]
\addplot {rnd};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just an idea: did you considered to include you first plot inside a groupplot with `group size=1 by 1`? May be this way `pgfplots` make same adjustments as with other groupplots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. Using a matrix in combination with the boundingbox settings for every plot leads to a correct alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[] {
\begin{axis} [xlabel=x, ylabel=y, height=2cm,width=0.5\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
\\};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{2em}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[row sep=0.01\textwidth, column sep=0.01\textwidth] {
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
&
\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,yticklabel pos=right,height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
\\
\begin{axis}[height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth,scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
&
\begin{axis}[yticklabel pos=right,height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```