# How to expand a plot in a matrix over 2 or more matrix elements?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I use a matrix to arrange and align plots in a groupplot (as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-to-set-bounding-boxes-of-groupplots-for-aligning-purposes/145001#145001)) and I want to create a groupplot with one subplot which have the size of for example two subplots as shown below.

[image]

I wrote the following LaTeX code and I am looking for an option that allows me to expand a figure over two matrix elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[row sep=0.01\textwidth, column sep=0.01\textwidth] {

\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
&

\\
\begin{axis}[height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth,scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
&
\begin{axis}[yticklabel pos=right,height=4cm+0.01\textwidth,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);

\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the `groupplots` library. It does not have direct support for such constructs, so I shift the final subplot vertically with `yshift`. The height of the final subplot is calculated from the height of the other subplots and the distance between them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro\plotw{3cm} % width of subplots
\pgfmathsetmacro\ploth{2cm} % height of smaller subplots
\pgfmathsetmacro\vsep{5pt}  % vertical separation between subplots
\pgfmathsetmacro\hsep{5pt}  % horizontal separation between subplots

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
       group size=2 by 2,
       vertical sep=\vsep,
       horizontal sep=\hsep,
       x descriptions at=edge bottom},
    height=\ploth,
    width=\plotw,
    scale only axis]

\nextgroupplot
\addplot [blue] {rnd};


\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]
% second plot should be empty    

\nextgroupplot
\addplot [red] {rnd};

\nextgroupplot[
   yticklabel pos=right,
   height=2*\ploth + \vsep,
   yshift=\ploth+\vsep]
\addplot [green] {rnd};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noticed that the `trim axis group left, trim axis group right` seems not to work in this case because of the empty plot. A solution is to use the definition of this option and replace it by `trim left={(group c1r1.south west)},trim axis={(group c2r2.south east)}` or anything adapted to your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Because we cannot nest pgf matrices yet, I suggest the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\matrix[row sep=0.01\textwidth, column sep=0.01\textwidth] {

\begin{axis}[xtick=\empty,height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
%&
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=2cm,width=0.245\textwidth,scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[yticklabel pos=right,height=4cm+0.01\textwidth,width=0.245\textwidth, scale only axis]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path
(current axis.south west)
rectangle (current axis.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering why the height of the two subplots and the horizontal distance fits to the height of the "big" plot although it is not considered in the code. I have to think about the control options for the vertical distance if I want to use this tabular solution...