# pgfplots - trim axis of groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Using the `groupplots` library of pgfplots, it is fairly simple to create aligned plots.
Now, I want to move the left axes into the margin of my document. Typically, that is, if I had a single plot without `groupplots`, this could be done with a combination of `trim axis left` and `scale only axis`.

Consider the following example. I want to create four plots, aligned in a 2x2 manner.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=2 by 2},
        width=0.499\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        ]

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x};

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x*x};

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {1};

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {-x};

    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Applying `trim axis left` and `scale only axis`, however, now trims not only the left axis of the left plots, but all the left plots. Probably this is because every subplot trims everything left of it, which includes the left plots in case of the right ones.

I tried to apply these options locally via the optional argument of `\nextgroupplot`, but it did not work. There is a similar question [about aligning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144947/how-to-set-bounding-boxes-of-groupplots-for-aligning-purposes), but I would prefer a solution that includes `groupplots`. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but is there a specific reason for your figures to be in the margins ?

Comment: There is a special version of `trim left` Mads for groupplots I think, look in the manual.

Comment: @BambOo, there are no special reasons for it, I just happen to like. Personal preferences, you could phrase it.

Comment: @segenen, OK, I have personal preferences too :). It's just that people sometimes ask questions to solve a problem that actually is the consequence of an underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim axis group left`, which is tailored for `groupplots`. In your example, you might also need `\noindent`, but whether that is needed in your actual document depends, for example, whether the `tikzpicture` is in a `figure` environment or not.

If you want the right axis border aligned with the right side of the text as well, you could set the `horizontal sep`, and then set `width` to `0.5\textwidth` minus half that `horizontal sep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis group left]
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
          group size=2 by 2,
          horizontal sep=30pt
         },
        width=0.5\textwidth-15pt, % subtract half the horizontal sep
        scale only axis,
        ]

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x};

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {x*x};

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {1};

        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot {-x};

    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Is there an elegant way to align the left border with the text, too?

Comment: @segenen See updated answer for a quick hack.